# How do I debug GIMP plugins? Where is the output?

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

I am making a plug in in Python for GIMP on Windows. [This page](http://gimpbook.com/scripting/notes.html) suggests running it from the shell or looking at ~/.xsession-errors. Neither work. I am able to run it from the cmd shell as:

```
gimp-2.8.exe -c --verbose
```

From [here](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=751). This causes the output from `pdb.gimp_message(...)` to go to a terminal, but only works when everything is running as expected. I get no output on crashes. I tried print statements, they go nowhere. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969820/plugins-usually-dont-work-how-do-i-debug) is a similar problem.

Running it from Python-Fu console gets me nowhere. I need to comment out `import gimpfu` as it raises errors and I don't get GTK working. Even if the plugin registers and shows on the menu, when there is some error I don't know where to look for hints.

1. Can I refresh a plugin without restarting GIMP?
2. Can I run plugins from the Python-Fu shell as opposed to importing them to make sure they parse?
3. Is there an error-log?
4. How to run GIMP on Windows from a shell to see output? Am I better off under Cygwin or VirtualBox?
5. How to connect Winpdb to a Python process that runs in GIMP?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> 1- can i refresh a plugin without restarting gimp ? (so at least my
>   slow-morph will be faster )

You must restart GIMP when you add a script or change register(). 
No need to restart when changing other parts of the script -- it runs as a separate process and will be re-read from disk each time.

helpful source: 
    http://gimpbook.com/scripting/notes.html

> 2- can i run plug-ins from the python-fu shell. (as opposed to just
>   importing them to make sure they parse.)

Yes, you can access to your registered plug-in in `python-fu` console as:

```
>>> pdb.name_of_registerd_plug-in
```

And can call it like:

```
>>> pdb.name_of_registerd_plug-in(img, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Also in `python-fu` dialog console, you can click to `Browse ..` option and find your registered plug-in, 
and then click `Apply` , to import it to `python-fu` console.

helpful source: 
    http://registry.gimp.org/node/28434

> 3- is there an error-log i am missing, or something to that effect?

To log, you can define a function like this:

```
def gimp_log(text):
    pdb.gimp_message(text)
```

And use it in your code, whenever you want.

To see log of that, in `gimp` program, open `Error Console` from `Dockable Dialogs` in `Windows` menu, otherwise a message box will be pop up on every time you make a log.

Also you can redirect `stdin` and `stdout` to a file,:

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open('er.txt', 'a')
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'a')
```

When you do that, all of `exceptions` will go to `err.txt` and all of print out will be go to `log.txt` 
Note that open file with `a` option instead of `w` to keep log file.

helpful sources:

[How do I output info to the console in a Gimp python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955834/how-do-i-output-info-to-the-console-in-a-gimp-python-script)

http://www.exp-media.com/content/extending-gimp-python-python-fu-plugins-part-2

> 4- is there a way to run gimp on windows from a shell to see output ?
>   (am i better off under cygwin (or virtualbox.. ))?

I got some error for that, but may try again ...

> 5- i haven't yet looked up how to connect winpdb to an existing
>   process. how would i go about connecting it to a python process that
>   runs inside gimp?

First install [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/download/) , and also [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) ( Winpdb GUI depends on wxPython)

Note that `Gimp` has own python interpreter, and may you want to install `winpdb` to  your default python interpreter or to gimp python interpreter.

If you install `winpdb` to your default python interpreter, then you need to copy `rpdb2.py` installed file  to `..\Lib\site-packages` of gimp python interpreter path.

After that you should be able to import `pdb2` module from `Python-Fu` console of gimp:

```
GIMP 2.8.10 Python Console
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>>> import rpdb2
>>>
```

Now in your plug-in code, for example in your main function add following code:

```
import rpdb2 # may be included out side of function.
rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger("pass") # a password that will asked by winpdb
```

Next, go to gimp and run your python plug-in, when you run your plug-in, it will run and then wait when reach to above code.

Now to open `Winpdb GUI`  go to `..\PythonXX\Scripts` and run `winpdb_.pyw`.

(Note that when using Winpdb for remote debugging make sure any [firewall](http://winpdb.org/docs/requirements/) on the way has TCP port 51000 open. Note that if port 51000 is taken Winpdb will search for an alternative port between 51000 and 51023.)

Then in `Winpdb GUI` from `File` menu select `attach` and give `pass` as password to it, and then  you can see your plug-in script on that list, select it and start your debug step by step.

[image: debug python gimp plugin with Winpdb]

helpful resource:
    [Installing PyGIMP on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592607/installing-pygimp-on-windows)

Useful sources:

http://wiki.gimp.org/index.php/Hacking:Plugins

http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html

http://wiki.elvanor.net/index.php/GIMP_Scripting

http://www.exp-media.com/gimp-python-tutorial

http://coderazzi.net/python/gimp/pythonfu.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-autogimp/os-autogimp-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 4):

as noted in [How do I output info to the console in a Gimp python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955834/how-do-i-output-info-to-the-console-in-a-gimp-python-script/15637932#15637932)

add

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open( 'c:\\temp\\gimpstderr.txt', 'w') 
sys.stdout = open( 'c:\\temp\\gimpstdout.txt', 'w')
```

at the beginning of the plug in file.

Answer (score 2):

I am a newbie to python, but I would like to give a shout-out, first to winpdb, and then to this comment for integrating winpdb into GIMP.
This same procedure works as well for LibreOffice 4.

If I may be allowed to vent a little; I have a moderate amount of experience with Visual Basic, more or less at a hobbiest level, but I decided a few years ago to get into OpenOffice when MicroSoft threatened to abandon VB for the Mac.  I don't want to say that VB in OpenOffice was onerous, but the lack of anything resembling an IDE is tedious.  Now, with winpdb, I will never be looking back.  It's python from here on out, baby.

Steps taken:

-- As suggested by Omid above, I first got winpdb running out of GIMP (relatively painless).

-- I copied the rpdb2.py file to C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4\program\python-core-3.3.3\lib\site-packages\rpdb2.py.  (Win 7, LibreOffice 4.4.03)

-- I edited the HelloWorld.py file in C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4\share\Scripts\python directory (saved in WinPDb_HelloWorld.py to same directory).

```
# HelloWorld python script for the scripting framework
# This file is part of the LibreOffice project.
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. blah, blah, blah ...

import rpdb2
#rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger("Your Password Here")    # << DON'T start debugger here.
    # It only gets you lost in the LO python wrapper when debugging.

def HelloWorldPython( ):
    """Prints the string 'Hello World(in Python)' into the current document"""

    # start debugger INSIDE function, where it will be called from LO Macros -- Duh!!
    rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger("YourPasswordHere") 

    #get the doc from the scripting context which is made available to all scripts
    desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop() 
    #... etc., see HelloWorld.py
```

WinPDb_HelloWorld appears under LibreOffice Macros in the Macro Selector (see https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language for more on that).

(can't show you a picture - posting as a guest)